# WPF ListView with a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

We have ListView with ComboBox. I am binding data to listView on the button click. And I want to show combobox with  selected value . When we set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" then it's updating all value of combobox but when we set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" then combobox not showing selected value. Why?  I am using MVVM Model for bind data for both list view and combobox not  hard coded.If you have solution then please share with us.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Part ID">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="PartIdListViewRadComboBox"  
                CanAutocompleteSelectItems="True" IsEditable="True"  
                Width="105" Height="30" Margin="4,4,4,4" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"  StaysOpenOnEdit="False"  
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ProductID}"
                DisplayMemberPath="PartID" EmptyText="Part ID" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                ItemsSource="{ Binding RelativeSource=
                              {RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},
                              Path=DataContext.ProductModel.ListViewComboboxProductListCollection}"
                OpenDropDownOnFocus="True" 
                TextSearchMode="Contains" IsFilteringEnabled="True" 
                IsTextSearchEnabled="True">

                <!--
                <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                 -->
                       <!--
                       <si:CallMethodAction MethodName="SelectionChanged" 
                        TargetObject="{Binding}" /> -->
                        <!--
                       <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
                          {RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},
                          Path=DataContext.PartIdComboboxChangedComand}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PartIdListViewRadComboBox}"/>
                   </ie:EventTrigger>
               </ie:Interaction.Triggers>-->
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
       </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you had in your actual code or if it's just an error in your question, but you have `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="Fa"` instead of `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"`.

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="Fa". it's by mistake  do not care this. Please read IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"

Comment: if any body have knowledge of WPF with MVVM then share your view  other wise don't waste time

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say "then combobox not showing selected value" does that mean the combobox does not have any items available for selection? Or does that mean there are values in the combobox dropdown, but the selected value is empty?

Comment: yes, selected value is empty

Comment: Try `SelectedValuePath="ProductID"` or, if it's your intention, `SelectedValuePath="PartID"`

Comment: No, it's not working. Please provide any other solution

Comment: Hi All WPF Expert, Please read my question and provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

My last idea is to use an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ... >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PartID}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    ...
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: combobox inside ListView

Comment: It's  producing error ' Additional information: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.'